# Adding an external jar file to an OSGi application causes issues

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, osgi, osgi-bundle

I am new to Java OSGi programming. I am creating a new bundle called *com.myManager* and adding it to an existing application which has many bundles.

This bundle I am creating depends on an external jar file called *jsoup-1.12.1* which is used for parsing html files. I can add this dependency via eclipse, and my bundle builds fine.

However, when I try to add my bundle to the main *bndrun* application, I get the below pasted error. Unfortunately i'm not able to understand what is required here.

I guess that we can't just simply add external jar files the way I did? Thanks in advance.

```
Resolution failed. Capabilities satisfying the following requirements could not be found:
[<<INITIAL>>]
  ⇒ osgi.identity: (osgi.identity=com.myManager)
      ⇒ [com.myManager version=0.0.0]
          ⇒ osgi.wiring.package: (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.jsoup))
```

Comment: The OSGi container is complaining that it can't resolve the package `org.jsoup`, which your new bundle depends on. You have to either deploy the jsoup library as a bundle (if it packaged as such), or embed the library into your bundle.

Comment: @gioranv Embed the library in my bundle. How would I go about that? I am already adding it in to a lib folder in my bundle and  configuring it as a dependency for my bundle via Eclipse. Thanks

Comment: Follow the advice from Christian's answer. Fortunately, most libraries are packaged as bundles these days.

Answer (score 3):

Until now you only added jsoup to the build time dependencies of your bundle. Using jsoup in your bundle then creates a import package declaration in your bundle manifest. This is expected and not a problem.
The error you see is that at assembly time (when bnd creates the runbundles list) of your application you have no bundle in the repository that can provide this package.

Jsoup already is an OSGi bundle. Simply add it to the bundles of your application and you are done. How to add jsoup to the bundles depends on how you assemble your application. For eclipse pde you would add it to the target platform. For apache karaf you would add it to your feature.

For the new bndrun with the maven build you simply add jsoup to the pom where you build your repository. Like in this [example](https://github.com/cschneider/osgi-best-practices/blob/bb5eb491cdefb0817a12c630bb51d03fd8666b4c/app/pom.xml#L144-L148). Having the bundle in the repository allows bndtools to select the bundle for your application if there is a requirement for it.

Comment: Thanks. I still don't understand fully tho. I have only the jar file, I add it to dependencies. I don't see jsoup come up as an option to add it as a bundle to my application.